# url from mysql db with <A> tag in table with php

Tags: php, mysql

I couldn't find a question with exactly what I want to know and since I already have the majority of code written and just need this little part to work it's hard to follow someone elses question.

this is the part that doesn't work:

```
echo "<TD width='220px' style='padding:5px;'>" . "<a href='>" . $row['horselink'] ."'><strong>" . $row['name'] . "</strong></a></td>";
```

I want the a href to collect the data from the column horselink so it links the name. I have tried several way but I just can't get it work. Anyone have a good tip or idea how the write the link/url part correctly since the rest of the table works just fine.

complete code looks like this:

```
 <?php
                        include("conn.php"); //Databas koppling
                        mysql_set_charset("utf8");
                        $result = mysql_query("SELECT name, horselink, born, gender, discipline, breed, sire, dam FROM Horse WHERE horsetype = 'young' ORDER by born");
                        //Hämtar all information från kurser


                            echo "<table id='trhover' class='tableclassen' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='1'>";
                            echo "<TR class='trhead' style='text-transform:uppercase; background-color: #6e3f47;'>";
                            echo "<TD width='220px' style='padding:5px;'><strong>Name<strong></TD>";
                            echo "<TD width='60px' style='padding:5px;'><strong>Dob</strong></TD>";
                            echo "<TD width='90px' style='padding:5px;'><strong>Gender</strong></TD>";
                            echo "<TD width='110px' style='padding:5px;'><strong>Discipline</strong></TD>";
                            echo "<TD width='120px' style='padding:5px;'><strong>Breed</strong></TD>";
                            echo "<TD width='160px' style='padding:5px;'><strong>Sire</strong></TD>";
                            echo "<TD width='160px' style='padding:5px;'><strong>Dam</strong></TD>";
                            echo "</TR>";


                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) // Skriver ut all information i en tabell
                         {
                            echo "<TR>";
                            echo "<TD width='220px' style='padding:5px;'>" . "<a href='>" . $row['horselink'] ."'><strong>" . $row['name'] . "</strong></a></td>";
                            echo "<TD width='60px' style='padding:5px;'>" . $row['born'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<TD width='90px' style='padding:5px;'>" . $row['gender'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<TD width='110px' style='padding:5px;'>" . $row['discipline'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<TD width='120px' style='padding:5px;'>" . $row['breed'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<TD width='160px' style='padding:5px;'>" . $row['sire'] . "</td>";
                            echo "<TD width='160px' style='padding:5px;'>" . $row['dam'] . "</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                         }
                            echo "</table>";

                    ?>
```

Comment: You want mysql_fetch_assoc

Comment: @xd6_: The default result type for [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) is **`MYSQL_BOTH`**, so that should work just fine.

Comment: "<a href='>" replace with "<a href='"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
echo /* ... */ "<a href='>" . $row['horselink'] ."'><strong>" /* ... */;
```

has an extra **`>`** in it. It should be:

```
echo /* ... */ "<a href='" . $row['horselink'] ."'><strong>" /* ... */;
```

**And**:

- You should **not** use the deprecated **mysql** functions. Use [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [**mysqli**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).
- You should escape your output with [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).
- It is considered good practice to markup your table headings with `<THEAD>` and `<TH>` elements.